# Logstash http_poller plugin to authenticate to Jira is failing

Tags: jira, logstash

I am having an issue with the Logstash configuration file to retrieve content from jira. My configuration file is below

```
input {
    http_poller {
        urls => {
            test1 => {
                method => get
                url => "jira url for specific issue"
                headers => {
                    Accept => "application/json"
                }
                auth => {
                    user => "username"
                    password => "passwd"
                }
            }   
        }
        request_timeout => 60
        interval => 3600
        codec => "json"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {}
    stdout {}
}
```

When I query the new index created I get the following message from the results:

```
    "errorMessages" : [ "You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.", "Login Required" ],
```

I have tried variations for the username such as username@company.com but that didn't work out either. I have also verified by a regular curl command with a given username and password that the JIRA authentication worked. Does anyone see the problem with Logstash?

Comment: How do you specify the username and password on the curl command-line?

Comment: My curl command goes something like this: curl -u username:password -X GET .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a workaround to this. There is another Logstash input plugin called **exec** which periodically runs a shell command. Since I can connect to Jira with curl, I just use that to retrieve the data.

Another solution that is also possible, if one is not concerned about using old versions of elasticsearch, is to use the river plugin below:
https://github.com/searchisko/elasticsearch-river-jira. It is amazing and can do almost everything you need.